# getting file not found exception

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I have my android activity  :

```
try {  
            File root=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
            Log.i("root",root.toString());  
                            File dir=new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/downloads");  
            dir.mkdirs();  
            file=new File(dir,"mytext.txt");  
            FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file,true);  
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(out);  
            pw.println("Hello! Welcome");  
            pw.println("You are Here...!!!");  
            pw.flush();  
            pw.close();  
            try {  
                 out.close();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                e.printStackTrace();  
          }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

also added :

```
   <uses-permission android:name="androd.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but it throws me FileNotfound exception : 
01-13 09:06:44.442: WARN/System.err(419): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/downloads/mytext.txt (No such file or directory)

and if i add

```
 if(file.exists()){  
   System.out.println("file exists");  
  }  
  else{  
     System.out.println("No such Fileeeeeeeeee");  
   }
```

it moves into "else" part.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: You have to check the whether media is available or not using getExternalStorageState()  method.

Comment: It is available and its both readable and writeable.

Comment: can you explain whhat you're doing with "dir.mkdirs()"?

Comment: creating a new directory with complete path of sdcard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this,,it works for me

```
// create a File object for the parent directory
File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
// create a File object for the output file
File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, filename);
//now attach OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

[GO through this for more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Answer (score 7):

In Android 6 (Marshmallow) I had to explicitely check whether my app has permission `"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

Comment: How to check if the permission is granted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but please verify that there exists External Storage in your emulator or phone otherwise it will through exception.