# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/1358731920220.jpg (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, file, camera, uri

```
public class BeginTakePhotoScene extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_take_photo_scene);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        takephotobtn = new ImageButton(this);
        takephotobtn.setId(888);
        takephotobtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.take_photo_btn);
        takephotobtnparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        takephotobtnparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        takephotobtnparam.topMargin = margin.heightPixels * 9 / 10 - height;
        takephotobtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                mUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), String.valueOf(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
                camera.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
                camera.putExtra("return-data", false);
                startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);
            }
        });

        choosephotobtn = new ImageButton(this);
        choosephotobtn.setId(889);
        choosephotobtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.choose_photo_btn);
        choosephotobtnparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        choosephotobtnparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        choosephotobtnparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 888);
        choosephotobtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                uncroppedimage = getFilePath(selectedImageUri);

                Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

                cropIntent.setDataAndType(selectedImageUri, "image/*");

                cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

                cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

                cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
                cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);

                File tempFile;
                tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                mSavedUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
                cropIntent.putExtra("output", mSavedUri);

                cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);

            } else if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT) {
                Log.e("mUri", mUri.getPath());
                uncroppedimage = mUri.getPath();

                Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

                cropIntent.setDataAndType(mUri, "image/*");

                cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

                cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

                cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
                cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);

                File tempFile;
                tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                mSavedUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
                cropIntent.putExtra("output", mSavedUri);

                cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
            } else {
                Log.e("mSavedUri", mSavedUri.getPath());
                profileimage.setImageURI(mSavedUri);
                croppedimage = mSavedUri.getPath();

                profileimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                confirmbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                takephotobtnparam.topMargin = margin.heightPixels * 9 / 10
                        - height * 2;
            }
        }
    }

    private String getFilePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int colum_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(colum_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```

I log the `uri.getpath`, it return `file:///mnt/sdcard/1358731920220.jpg`. This link seem like got extra `/`. However, I not sure why it like this?

Comment: it is a file:// uri. The path is /mnt/sdcard... When you put them together you get file:///mnt/sdcard

Comment: Please ask a more specific question according to Title.

Comment: Maybe the Uri from storing the picture is usually `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/`... but the OP has it hardcoded to look in the root of sdcard...?

Comment: @herbertD I am asking specific question now, `file not found`

Comment: @t0mm13b What your mean?

Comment: Android stores pictures in the directory specified by the content provider, which is usually `DCIM/Camera` and that's referred to as by `Media.Images.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`...

Comment: I found the error, I log both uri which were before crop and after crop. However, after crop, the image did not save into sdcard that why it cannot find the file. How to save it?

Answer (score 2):

`cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);`

change to

`cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);`

will save the cropped image into sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in Manifest file, if you haven't added yet,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: have a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845534/getting-file-not-found-exception).