# Cannot catch exception, catch block is never reached

Tags: android, exception, try-catch

I have  code structurred in this way

```
public void generalMethod(){
   try{
     methodThatStartAsyncWebTask();
   catch(Exception e){
     offlineDataAlternativeMethod();
   }

}
```

the method

```
public void offlineDataAlternativeMethod(){
      try(
        loadArchivedFile();
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        reInitializeeData();
     }

}
```

The App crashes at line `loadArchivedFile();` that fails because doesn't found the file, but the strange thing is that catch block that invokes  `reInitializeeData();` isn't reached.

Why cannot reach catch block in anyway? Any idea?

This is the first time that see a similar issue. Any solution?

Comment: could you show some code of loadArchivedFile? you are not showing your stackTrace. e.printStackTrace();

Comment: the stacktrace is too long but simply that FileNotFound exception generated by `loadArchivedFile()` isn't captured as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[getting file not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845534/getting-file-not-found-exception)

Comment: try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845534/getting-file-not-found-exception

Comment: ok this works, thanks... but why the hell try catch doesn't work? FileNotFoundException should inherit from Exception, so I cannot understand the reason of this issue

Comment: Maybe class you used is only for java not for amdroid, then android vertual marchine occurs runtime errors, then virtual machine is dead. This is only my thought, i dont know why occured not yet