# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

> Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_black_48dp.png (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

trying to build project but file name changes all the time, error remain same

[image: Error message]

Comment: pls post build.gradle file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting file not found exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845534/getting-file-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just open this(app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_black_48dp.png) file directory and delete it.
2. Clean and Re-build your project.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes we can edit build folder...The logic behind this is when you clean or rebuild your project then gradle build system makes new files every time.

Comment: Right, it makes the files everytime. That was my point. This resource is being generated and cannot be removed via a clean because it is a `file with a user-mapped section open`

Comment: follow your steps but now file change with different names

Comment: post your logcat and build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

The Android Gradle plugin version 2.2.2 has an issue.

To resolve this issue you need to change your gradle plugin version in project setting:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete build folder in app then clean & rebuild project that works fine.